# Field in monad. Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
type Context = Map.Map VarName (Type, Integer)
type Memory = Map.Map Integer LitVal
type Functions = Map.Map VarName (Stmt, Context)

data InterpreterM stmts a = ExeInterpreter stmts a | PropInterpreter stmts a

newtype InterpreterMT stmts m a = InterpreterMT { runInterpreterMT :: stmts -> m (InterpreterM stmts a) }

type Interpreter = InterpreterMT Stmts (StateT (Memory, Functions) (ReaderT (Context, Context) (ErrorT String IO)))



instance (Monad m) => Monad (InterpreterMT s m) where
    return x = InterpreterMT $ \stmts -> return (ExeInterpreter stmts x)
    x >>= f = InterpreterMT $ \stmts -> do
        m <- runInterpreterMT x stmts 
        case m of
            (ExeInterpreter ss a) -> (runInterpreterMT (f a) ss)

data Stmts =  Statements Stmt Stmts | EmptyStmts

    nextStatement :: <HERE>
```

Hi,
As you can see `Stmts` has recursive definition. Now, I would like to implement `nextStatement` function but I cannot imagine how to do it in monad. 
Beyond monad it is simple but then, statements must be provided,  I mean:

```
nextStatement :: Stmts  -> Stmt
nextStatement (Statements s ss) =  s
nextStatement EmptyStatement = EmptyStatement
```

Comment: It appears that `EmptyStatement` is like a list of `Stmt`, not a single `Stmt`, so why is it valid as a return value from `nextStatement`? I think the same problem you are having with defining `nextStatement` is the same as trying to define `head :: [a] -> a` on the empty list. You can't, and that's why `head []` throws an error.

Comment: It is polite to include enough code that we can at least reproduce your problem. That means imports and all the type definitions needed -- e.g. what are `VarName`, `Type`, `LitVal`, `Stmt`? We can stub this stuff out, but in the future please include a minimal working example.

Comment: @DanielWagner I wanted to avoid putting too much code. I can attach now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you probably want something like this:

```
nextStatement :: MonadError String m => Stmts -> m Stmt
nextStatement (Statements s _) = return s
nextStatement EmptyStmts = throwError "nextStatement EmptyStmts"
```

In particular `Interpreter` is an instance of `MonadError String` and so this can also be given the type `Stmts -> Interpreter Stmt`. You can retrieve the `Stmts` from the `InterpreterMT` transformer in the usual `State`-like way, annotated with either `ExeInterpreter` or `PropInterpreter` as appropriate (I don't know which is appropriate so I just picked one):

```
getStmts :: Monad m => InterpreterMT stmts m stmts
getStmts = InterpreterMT (\stmts -> return (ExeInterpreter stmts stmts))
```

You should probably also implement the usual interfaces for `InterpreterMT`, giving an instance of `MonadTrans (InterpreterMT stmts)` and probably a few of `MonadError e m => MonadError e (InterpreterMT stmts m)` + the other `mtl` classes. Then you will be able to write

```
getStmts >>= nextStatement :: MonadError String m => InterpreterMT Stmts m Stmt
```

Comment: no,  note that `Stmts` is field of `InterpreterMT` monad while you get it as argument in function

Comment: @Gilgamesz Ugh, why is your `InterpreterMT` transformer set up in such a roundabout way? Anyway, give me a moment and I will show how to deal with the ugliness.

Comment: "You should probably also implement the usual interfaces for InterpreterMT, giving an instance of MonadTrans (InterpreterMT stmts) and probably a few of MonadError e m => MonadError e (InterpreterMT stmts m) + the other mtl classes. Then you will be able to write"
I don't understand what do you mean.